# Proving a simple integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f(x)$ is a smooth continuously differentiable function defined for all $x$ (real domain) where $f(x)\geq 0$ (that is to say, $f(x)$ is everywhere strictly positive). Next, consider a subdomain $[a,b]$ with $a<b$. Suppose $\gamma\geq 0$. How can we prove the following assertion
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} f(x)e^{-\gamma x} dx \geq |f(b)e^{-\gamma b}-f(a)e^{-\gamma a}|\ ?
\end{equation}
And does it hold for arbitrarily large $\gamma$? I know intuitively it makes sense that since $f(x)$ is always positive, then the integral from $a$ to $b$ must be larger than the difference of the endpoints of the function, but I don't know how to prove this rigorously.

Comment: With the substitution $g(x) =  f(x)e^{-\gamma x} $ this is equivalent to $\int_a^b g(x) dx \ge g(b) - g(a)$, and that is wrong in general, a simple counterexample is $\int_0^1 x dx$.

Comment: as soon as $f(x) e^{-\gamma x}$ is strictly convex with $f(a) = 0$ or $f(b)=0$ it is quite clearly wrong. Imagine the right side beeing the integral of the line which lies in the epigraph of $fe^{-\gamma x}$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. For $a=0$, $b=1$, $\gamma=0$, and $f(x)=x$, you would get
$$\frac{1}{2} =\int_0^1 x \mathrm{dx} \geq 1$$